# How many rings exist when ring is subspace of finite dimentional vector space?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Suppose we have ring $R[M]$ over monoid $M$ in real number $R$.The number of generators for the monoid, is finite. Now suppose that every ring element $r$ has decomposition in finite linear basis of n-elements. So ring is subspace of n-dimensional vector space.

**How many rings, depending on n has this property?** Could You give me some references ( books, preprints, articles) when such theorem is stated or proved?

---

**Motivation:** Here [monoid ring and some structure within it -  how is it called?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14253/monoid-ring-and-some-structure-within-it-how-is-it-called) in a comment to the question, Scott Carnahan wrote:

> The existence of the decomposition of
>   elements of R[M] implies the ring is a
>   subspace of a 4-dimensional real
>   vector space. There are many such
>   rings, but only finitely many monoid
>   rings of dimension less than 5.

**Clarification of the problem:**

I have finitely presented noncommutative monoid with unity and two generators $g_1,g_2$: M = F/Rel where $Rel = \{g_1^2 = e , g_2^2 = g_2 \}$, $e$ is unit element and $F$ is free monoid over two generators. Because of relations $Rel$ every elemet in monoid has form for example $g = g_1g_2g_1g_2...g_1g_2$ ( alternating finite sequence with subscripts 1212... or 2121...). Different monoid elements contains different number of multiplications. It is very simple although infinite multiplicative structure.

Then I consider monoid ring over reals $R[M]$. Every element in $R[M]$ has form:

(1) $t = r_1g_1 + r_2g_2 r_3g_1g_2+r_4g_2g_1+ r_5g_1g_2g_1 + ...+r_p g_ig_kg_i...g_s+ ...$ and so on.  $r_i \in R$ and $g_i \in M$.

Note that in general monomial element $g_ig_k...g_s$ every subscript has value in $\{1,2\}$ and no two following each other subscripts are the same ( they alternate like in sequence like $1212..$ or $2121..$. Of course this is standard ring definition.

In structure, I would like to describe You here, I have strange additional property: there is element $g_3$ in ring $R[M]$ ( **but it is not monoid element!**) which allows following decomposition:

For every $r \in R[M]$  we have

$r= r_0 e + r_1 g_1 +r_2 g_2 +r_3 g_3$

Look: there are **only four terms in decomposition, even if You decompose general ring element in the form of (1)**. However after such decomposition I may **only multiply** such elements and **not add them**. In some way it looks like vector space. From the other side such decomposition may be treated as another monoid. So in fact decomposition as above, I trying to treat as some kind of "parametrization" of ring elements. Indeed it is element of some vector space, but there are further requirements on coefficients $r_i$ ( which I do not need to describe here, they in fact are part of monoid definition).

As far as I know this is not standard ring property -  maybe I am wrong. If I think about for example polynomial ring (that in simple case is real ring over multiplicative monoid generated by one generator $x$)  such decomposition is not possible.

Comment: Is your question is equivalent to asking: how many monoids are there which have $n$ elements?

Comment: @Mariano: probably not! But in fact I do not know...

Answer (score 1):

Your $M$ is infinite, so the ring monoid $R[M]$ is infinite dimensional. In particular, there does *not* exist an element $g_3$ with the property you state, for otherwise $R[M]$ would be simultaneously 4 dimensional.

Comment: So there are two possibilities: I made mistake in calculus on 2x2 matrices ( performed within Sage software), or I miss some important elements of my construction to describe here. Does it has any influence that decomposition do not agree with ring structure? That is $r+r'$ ( regarded as decomposed) is not ring element whilst r*r' is? I do not want to describe the whole big picture of my construction because it is rather reach structure over 2x2 matrix monoid and may be not interesting for anyone...

Comment: @kakaz, it is impossible to tell which of the two options holds, becaus eyou have not given us any information. In any case, an infinite dimensional vector space is not a 4-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Yes Yu are right, and I am sorry for that. But details are too complicated to write it here. I have monoid M of 2x2 matrices with $det=1$  and this gives some nonlinear constraints on $r_i$ coefficients. So even if decomposition exists and it reflects some ring structure ( multiplicative one) it is not any type of "ring of 4 generators". Probably it would be better to say that I found function from $R[M]$ to another monoid (where elements are parametrised as in post). But it is interesting that it is so small.... Maybe I will try to describe it in detail in the future. Thanks a lot!